# Check if Pointer Points to Nil Slice

Tags: pointers, go, null, slice

I have a function that takes a pointer to any slice, and said parameter is of type `interface{}`.

I need to make sure that the pointer does not point to a `nil` slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Dog struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    var slicePointer interface{}

    // We only want slices that were initialized with `make()`.
    dogs1 := make([]Dog, 0)
    fmt.Println("dogs1 == nil:", dogs1 == nil)

    slicePointer = &dogs1
    fmt.Println("slicePointer == nil:", slicePointer == nil)

    fmt.Println("-----")

    // This needs to be caught, as the slice is `nil`.
    var dogs2 []Dog
    fmt.Println("dogs2 == nil:", dogs2 == nil)

    slicePointer = &dogs2
    fmt.Println("slicePointer == nil:", slicePointer == nil)
}
```

Output:

```
dogs1 == nil: false
slicePointer == nil: false
-----
dogs2 == nil: true
slicePointer == nil: false
```

Is there a way to do such a check in Golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell if a non-nil interface has a nil-pointer value using reflection:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(slicePointer).Elem().IsNil())
```

For the safest approach:

```
  if slicePointer!=nil {
    v:=reflect.ValueOf(slicePointer)
    if v.Kind()==reflect.Ptr {
      fmt.Println(v.Elem().IsNil())
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Just a note: you should check value's `Kind()` when using reflect, or it will panic.

Comment: @leafbebop correct. I included that as well in the answer.

Comment: Note that while you *can* do this, you almost certainly *shouldn't*. This question is for @FloatingSunfish: If the pointer *isn't* nil, what do you plan to do with it? Show the actual code. It starts with: `p := slicePointer.([]Dog)`, doesn't it? Now add `if p == nil` to that code, and answer a second question: why did you do all the complicated `reflect` testing first, when `if p == nil` is so easy?

Comment: There are one or two cases where there's a satisfactory answer to the second question, which starts with: "I plan to write the `p := ...` assignment in another function, and there will be dozens of such functions and I don't want each one to require an `if p == nil` test at the front." It's satisfactory because it provides a good reason for doing the generic test earlier, in the earlier function—but it's still a bit weak, because `if p == nil` is not a complicated test, while the reflect test is very complicated.

Comment: @torek I am passing a slice pointer to the `Select` function from https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx and I want to enforce that my code will only be working with slices that have been initialized through `make()` as that is what we need for our project.

Comment: It looks like the way you're supposed to _call_ `Select` is like this: `var s []T` and then `err := Select(q, &s, query, arg1, arg2)`. There's no need to use a separate `var x interface{}` followed by `x = &s` followed by `Select` with `&x` as its argument. See https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Select

Comment: Yup, `Select()` works with both structs and slices. I meant to say that we only wanted to work with non-nil slices. Thanks!